# Best or good way to loop through single dictionary to get particular key, value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

Here is a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'id': '5f7756f5141a30516ba0fe1d', 
       'name': 'Flask', 
       'desc': '', 
       'descData': None, 
       'closed': False, 
       'idOrganization': None, 
       'idEnterprise': None, 
       'pinned': False,}
```

What I need: 
A good code sample that uses a loop/filter/map (whatever it takes) to get this filtered result:

```
{'name': 'Flask', 'idOrganization': None}
```

My Problem: 
I assumed I would loop through the keys with dummy code something like:

```
for the_key in my_dict:
    if the_key == 'name' or 'idOrginization':
       print (the key with its value)
```

I can get keys back from if statement, but I need the values along with it as well.

Comment: `for key, value in my_dict.items():`

Comment: why do you need to loop? `print({"name": my_dict["name"], "idOrganization": my_dict["idOrganization"]})`

Answer (score 1):

`{i: my_dict[i] for i in ['name', 'idOrganization']}`

Comment: Python dict value complexity is 0(1)

Answer (score -1):

You can use items() function

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    print(k, ' = ', v)
```

You can then use `in` for your conditional check to avoid several `or` as below:

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    if k in ('name', 'idOrginization',):
        print(k, ' = ', v)
```